# Copying a cell + associated columns to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, data-analysis

I'm pretty new to VBA, and I have been trying to use it to accomplish some data analysis for my lab. I know exactly what I want to do, and I think I have gotten pretty close, however can't seem to execute.

I have 2 sheets (let's call them Data and Blank for simplicity). What I would LOVE to do is copy over some cells from Data and put them onto Blank. Ideally, I want all of my data generated from this code to start on B1 (Need column A on Blank for self-generated data)

1. I would like to use a command action (let's say Ctr + Shift + W) to prompt a GUI that asks me to enter a cell that I want to copy over from Data.
2. So In B1, I would get the value of the cell that I entered in the GUI (pulling from Data that cell's value).
3. To take it a step further, I would also like to have 2 additional cells generated on my Blank sheet. I want to add 2 cells that can be pulled from X row (whichever row my GUI-entered cell was in), the X and X columns (just variables to generalize).

To put it all together, I can make an example. I type Ctr + Shift + W. I am prompted to enter a cell. Given that it is not empty, I would type in the cell G4. G4's value from Data would upload onto B1 of Blank. I also want data from columns E and D (these never change, so no need to have to enter it in each time). In C1, the value of E4 and in D1, the value of V4.

I want to be able to be active in column A, so as I am entering something in A1 I can run the command and generate data for A1 to D1. When I finish entering in A2, I will want to run the command once I am in B2, so that I will generate values for B2, B3, and B4

```vb
Sub CopyDataToTest()
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim blankSheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Set references to Data and Blank sheets
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set blankSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blank")
    
    ' Prompt user to select a cell in Data sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourceCell = Application.InputBox("Select a cell in Data to copy", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if user selected a cell
    If Not sourceCell Is Nothing Then
        ' Copy value to B1 in Test sheet
        blankSheet.Range("B1").Value = sourceCell.Value
        
        ' Copy values from columns H and D in Data sheet to C1 and D1 in Blank sheet
        blankSheet.Range("C1").Value = dataSheet.Cells(sourceCell.Row, 8).Value ' Column H
        blankSheet.Range("D1").Value = data.Cells(sourceCell.Row, 4).Value ' Column D
        
        ' Activate the column A cell in Blank sheet
        blankSheet.Activate
        blankSheet.Range("A" & sourceCell.Row).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's what I've come up w so far. I think my issue is towards the end. Maybe during "activation" When I run this, I have the correct values for the associated columns in C and D. My issue is I cannot get the B column to generate anything. And actually, when it runs it goes to the associated row (let's say I typed F6 in the GUI so in this case it would go to F6 in Blank), however it is blank. Also, it seems I cannot do more than 1 entry. I want to add an entry, have B1 C1 and D1 generated, and then carry on to row 2, type in a cell, have B2 C2 and D2 generated, and so on.

I've tried to look at other answered questions on here + watched many videos, and was able to come up w this. Tried to correct it w/ ChatGPT. Thought it helped a little, but honestly not sure at this point.

Answer (score 0):

- There is a typo in `data.Cells(sourceCell.Row, 4).Value`. It should be `dataSheet`.
- `I am entering something in A1 I can run the command` So `blankSheet` is the active sheet when GUI is showed up. If users just select a cell (w/o change active sheet) or input a cell reference (eg. type in G4). Then `sourceCell` is a range object on `blankSheet`. It might be a blank cell. Then there is nothing on cell B1 after running the code.

Change:

- Activate `blankSheet` before pop up inputbox ( GUI )
- Add `If` clause to validate `sourceCell`

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopyDataToTest()
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim blankSheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Set references to Data and Blank sheets
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set blankSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blank")
    dataSheet.Activate '**
    ' Prompt user to select a cell in Data sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourceCell = Application.InputBox("Select a cell in Data to copy", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if user selected a cell
    If Not sourceCell Is Nothing Then
        If sourceCell.Parent.Name = "Data" Then '**
            ' Copy value to B1 in Test sheet
            blankSheet.Range("B1").Value = sourceCell.Value
            
            ' Copy values from columns H and D in Data sheet to C1 and D1 in Blank sheet
            blankSheet.Range("C1").Value = dataSheet.Cells(sourceCell.Row, 8).Value ' Column H
            blankSheet.Range("D1").Value = dataSheet.Cells(sourceCell.Row, 4).Value ' Column D
            
            ' Activate the column A cell in Blank sheet
            blankSheet.Activate
            blankSheet.Range("A" & sourceCell.Row).Select
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select a cell on sheet [Data]."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```